# Parsing string by '{ }'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

The format of the output is `[{uuid, Readings}, {uuid, Readings}, {uuid,Readings}]`
(Usually longer than this)

For example ... (All one string, just formatted to be easier on the eyes).

```
[{"uuid": "e2e38e4e-431d-508a-a5f9-e50eaffe6aab", "Readings": [[1351329301000.0, 0.0], [1351330202000.0, 0.0], [1351331102000.0, 0.0]]}, 

{"uuid": "8ed157d9-b31d-5075-bad6-69dfde7a34a4", "Readings": [[1351329301000.0, 0.0], [1351330202000.0, 0.0], [1351411200000.0, 494.0]]}, 

{"uuid": "8737f287-14df-5ccd-82df-e66ca7374b63", "Readings": [[1351329300000.0, 515.0], [1351330200000.0, 467.0], ]}]
```

I want to parse this so that I get everything in between the '{ }' symbols including the '{ }' symbols.

I don't want to separate anything else. Everything in between '{ }' symbols should stay together as one string.

Something that I'm also interested in is adding '[ ]' around each result at the end.

Simple example:

```
[ {"uuid": 1, "Readings": [[2,3], [2,6]]}, {"uuid": 1, "Readings": [[5,6], [7,7]]} ]
```

would result in an array where

```
element 0 = "[{"uuid": 1, "Readings": [[2,3], [2,6]]}]"
element 1 = "[{"uuid": 1, "Readings": [[5,6], [7,7]]}]"
```

Anyone know the regex expression to select something like this?
(I'm using ruby on rails btw)

Comment: Is that a JSON string? You could just do `JSON.parse(str)` to get it as a hash in Ruby.

Comment: Definitely. Regexes are not suitable for this kind of structure, and there already exists a better tool for the job.

Comment: Oh uhh maybe? Sorry, kinda new at this.

The application seems to run

`resp = http.request(request)
resp.body`

resp.body is what results as in the original question. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly "hacky", but I'd suggest parsing it using a JSON Parser (you'll have to see how exactly to do that yourself, I'm sure there's a library or something). Then, you can stringify each object in the returned array and put them in an array of strings.

Here's how I'd do it in javascript (you can adapt the workflow to RoR)

```
objArray = JSON.parse(jsonString);
stringArray=[];
for (i=0; i<objArray.length; i++) {
    stringArray.push("[" + JSON.stringify(objArray[i]) + "]");
}
```

**EDIT** WHY you want to do it so baffles me, because having the objects in an array would be sooo much more useful

Comment: What do you mean by that? I do want them in an array. (Such as the stringArray from your code). Or are you talking about breaking it up a different way?

Comment: Oh I get what you mean. Ok, that might have cleared some stuff up for me.